# How do I test a component method when using react-jss and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, testing, material-ui, enzyme, jss

I have basically this question:

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208

But my component is wrapped in the jss `withStyles` wrapper. I'm using the `shallow` [method created by Material-UI as outlined here.](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/)

eg:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    // Do something here
  }
  render() {
    // Component here
  }
}

const styles = {
     root: {}
}

export withStyles(styles)(Button);
```

The problem is - `wrapper.instance().handleClick()` will throw `handleClick() is not a function`.

How do I access the component itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dive](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md) to get to your component.

It seems MUI also comes with a "[dive](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/#shallow-rendering)" feature:

> The createShallow() function can be used for this situation. Aside from wrapping the enzyme API, it provides a dive and untilSelector option.

```
import { createShallow } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let shallow;

  before(() => {
    shallow = createShallow({dive: true}); // Shallow render the one non-DOM child of the current wrapper, and return a wrapper around the result.
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });
});
```